# Degrees of freedom for 2 samples with unequal variance (t-test)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, degrees-of-freedom

Is it possible for the degree of freedom to be more than the number of observation for an unpaired hypothesis test?

I am doing t-Test: Two-Sample Assuming Unequal Variances with sample size of 11 for each data set. However when I am calculating the df using excel data analysis tool I am gettin df = 19? How is this possible? If yes, what does this say about the data?

Comment: How are you calculating this? Are you writing functions in the cells (if so, what are they)? Is this a preexisting Excel function (if so, what)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it’s possible. The [formula for the number of degrees of freedom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch's_t_test#Calculations) is

$\frac{\left( {s_1^2 \over n_1} + {s_2^2 \over n_2} \right)^2 } 
 { \frac{s_1^4}{n_1^2 (n_1-1)} + \frac{s_2^4}{n_2^2 (n_2-1) }}$

where $n_i$ is the number of observations in the $i$th sample and $s_i$ is the standard deviation in this sample. If $s_1$ happens to be equal to $s_2$ and $n_1=n_2=n$, this reduces to $2(n-1)=2n-2$, i.e. the same number of degrees of freedom you would have with an *equal variance* *t*-test.

For your example $n=11$, so you would get 20 degrees of freedom, similar to your 19 degrees. So I would guess that your two standard deviations are very similar.

Note that for the equal sample size case, $2n-2$ is the *largest* number of degrees of freedom you *can* get. And it’s also easy to show that the lower bound on the number of degrees freedom you can get is $n-1$, which is what you would get if the sample standard deviation in one of the samples is very much larger than the sample standard deviation in the other sample ($n-1$ is the limit as $s_1/s_2$ tends to infinity).

Comment: To add on Karl's answer. A simplified way for calculating it is df= min(n1-1,n2-1).